# How to make an element visible inside an overlay? HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6whwk2?file=style.css

here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="my-overlay" padding [hidden]="overlayHidden">
    <ion-card class="card">
        <ion-card-content>
            Explore the App! See how everwell can help you achive your health goals.
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <div class="circle" (click)="hideOverlay()"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card {
  background-color: white;
}

.circle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.my-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ion-card {
  height: 9% !important;
  --color: #434d65;
  border-radius: 12px;
  bottom: 64px;
  position: absolute;
}

ion-card-content {
  padding-top: 11px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to place my ion-card above the overlay, to be visible and not beneath it how it's now. I tried to remove this from the class .cirle (see below), but this leads me to another problem which is the position of the circle which I can, of course, make it with margin to be placed on the right bottom of the page, but that's not responsive and doesn't look like a good approach.

```
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
```

I am new to coding and I am doing this as I learning project and I am struggling for a few days. If anyone has any suggestion I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using z-index: 1 :)

The z-index basically helps you determine the level of the item.

More here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

or for an easier read, since you're new to coding: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp